# ActionScript 3 processing XML; == operator is returning empty XMLList

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have an xml document like the below one that I am trying to parse using AS3.  I want to get all of the classes who have students playing Basketball.  I thought that I could do something like:

```
var sport:String = "BasketBall";
var bbClasses:XMLList = xml.classes.class.(students.student.commitments.comm==sport);
```

Unfortionatly this is returning me an empty XMLList.

```
<master>
    <classes>

        <class>
            <classID>1</classID>
            <teacherID>66</teacherID>
            <students>
                <student>
                    <studentID>1</studentID>
                    <studentDescription>bla bla</studentDescription>
                    <commitments>
                        <comm>Hockey</comm>
                        <comm>Dance</comm>
                        <comm>Basketball</comm>
                    </commitments>
                </student>
                <student>
                    <studentID></studentID>
                    <studentDescription>bla bla</studentDescription>
                    <commitments>
                        <comm>Hockey</comm>
                        <comm>Football</comm>
                        <comm>Basketball</comm>
                    </commitments>
                </student>
                <student>
                    ...
                </student>
                <student>
                    ...
                </student>
            </students>
        </class>
        <class>
            ...
        </class>    
        <class>
            ...
        </class>    
    </classes>
    <Commitments>
        ...
    </Commitments>
<master>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `contains` method, rather than `==` operator.

```
var bbClasses:XMLList =
    xml.classes.class.(students.student.commitments.comm.contains(sport));
```

ps: Watch out for your case.

"`BasketBall`" ins't "`Basketball`", so your E4X won't match.

Comment: Documentation is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/